# Efficient sampling of a high dimensional random vector

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo

I have a $D$ dimensional random vector $\mathbf{X}=[X_1, X_2,\dots,X_D]$, where each dimension is independent and follow some probability distribution: $X_i \sim p_i(.)$.My goal is to get samples of $\mathbf X$, say $\mathbf x^{(1)},\dots,x^{(n)}$, so that I can use them to do Monte Carlo simulations.

Since each dimension is independent, I am thinking of the following procedure, inspired by bootstrapping:

1. For each dimension $i=1,\dots, D$, draw $m$ samples. In the end, we have $D$ list, where each list is $m$ samples for the corresponding dimension: $(x_1^{(1)},\dots, x_1^{(m)}), \dots, (x_D^{(1)},\dots, x_D^{(m)})$.
2. To draw a sample $\mathbf x$, I randomly draw $x_i$ from the $m$ samples (with replacement) in the corresponding list for dimension $i$ above, such that in the end I have a sample $\mathbf x =[x_1,\dots, x_D]$.

It appears that this procedure can save a lot of compute. We have sampled only $mD$ numbers but it can generate $D^m$ distinct samples.

But I am not sure this procedure is valid. If it is indeed valid, then if I want $N$ samples of $\mathbf x$, how small can $m$ be? It is obviously not valid if $m=1$, because all $N$ samples would be the same. For a huge $m$, though, it intuitively becomes valid. What should be the smallest $m$?

It appears I have trouble analyzing it. Some help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Proceeding this way, the sample will not be iid, which may or not be a concern.